# Sending JSON data via AJAX to database

Tags: php, json

I'm having trouble sending a JSON array with AJAX to a PHP file which inserts the information in the correct columns in the database. The jquery and Json works fine, but it seems like the PHP side doesn't get the values correct, or maybe the json isn't encoded correct.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

JSON:

```
{
"Email": [
    {
        "Name": "My Name",
        "Phone": "1234567",
        "Email": "my@mail.com",
        "Interested_in": "Text text.",
        "User_id": "1"
    }
]
}
```

PHP:

```
$timeStamp = time();

$new_email = $_POST['NewMail'];

$email_info = $new_email->Email;

// New Email
mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $dbPrefix . "touches (date, user_id, name, phone, email, interested_in, seen, status) VALUES ('".safeSQL($timeStamp)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->User_id)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->Name)."','".safeSQL($email_info->Phone)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->Email)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->Interested_in)."', '0', '1')") or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
```

**UPDATE:**

Jquery for sending to PHP

```
    $( document ).on('click', '#send_touch', function(){

    new_email = [];

    new_email.push({
    Name: $('#name').val(),
    Phone: $('#phone').val(),
    Email: $('#email').val(),
    Interested_in: $('#interested_in').val(),
    User_id: $('#email_user_id').val()
    });

    new_email = JSON.stringify({Email: new_email}, null, "\t");

        $.ajax({
            url: "core.php",
            type: "post",
            data: { NewMail: new_email
                  },
            success: function(data){  

            },
            error: function(){
            }   
     });    

});
```

Also tried to change PHP to this:

```
$timeStamp = time();

$new_email = json_decode($_POST['NewMail']);

$email_info = $new_email->Email[0];

// New Hashtag
mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $dbPrefix . "touches (date, user_id, name, phone, email, interested_in, seen, status) VALUES ('".safeSQL($timeStamp)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->User_id)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->Name)."','".safeSQL($email_info->Phone)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->Email)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->Interested_in)."', '0', '1')") or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: You're not showing how you send the JSON data to your PHP script. If you're doing that correctly, you'll need to use `json_decode()` to unpack the data into a PHP object before you can access it.

Comment: I updated my answer with the $.ajax code

Comment: On a similar note I also send with AJAX a json string and by mistake I just assign it from it's _POST variable to a local to the script and it treats it as an array... Any ideas why this happens... I will  change it to using json_decode of course because lucky accidents are not trustworthy but I was curious. EDIT: Hmm when using json_decode it generates an error... EDIT2: Ok got it, it's because in the js the passed value is : {"4":["2","3"],"5":["1","2"],"6":["1","2","3"]}, the "4", "5", "6" should not have quotes

Comment: So similarly "Name": "My Name" should be Name: "My Name"

Comment: Ignore that I was wrong

Comment: So it seems that you can pass a json object as an argument in an AJAX request and PHP will automatically convert it to an array. If instead I passed **'** {"4":["2","3"],"5":["1","2"],"6":["1","2","3"]} **'** - notice the single quotes - then I would have to use json_decode etc etc... That's how I understood it at least. I hope I am right. This is for a website I am leasing so fingers crossed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing the decode on the php side:

```
$new_email = json_decode($_POST['NewMail']);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but it didn't work anyway.. Could be another issue then!

Comment: I thought someone else mentioned that in addition your Email object is an array...so you need to specify $email_info = $new_email->Email[0];  Wait looks like you fixed this.

Comment: I don't believe you need the "JSON.stringify" in the javascript side. I believe jquery (ajax call) is doing that for you.